# printglossaries doesnt output, Warning: File test.glo is empty

Tags: glossaries

Im using TexStudio and MiKTex 2.9 and the test file below (test.tex), I compile the document, call makeglosseries.exe and then recompile the document however `\printglossaries` does not oblige.

the following warning is returned

> Warning: File 'test.glo' is empty.

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[authoryearcitations]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\author{foo}
\title{foo}
\date{}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\printglossaries

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\label{cha:Introduction}

foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are not using any glossary in your document (`\gls`-like commands), so nothing is printed. Try adding `\glsaddall` to add all defined entries to your glossary.

Comment: You absolute legend! sorted.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Glossaries generated by the `glossaries` package behave like bibliographies.

If you don't "cite" anything, the glossary is not printed.

The corresponding `\cite` command is `\gls` and the equivalent of `\nocite{*}` to add all entries is `\glsaddall`.

So, for example, the following MWE, where I've added `\gls{latex}` prints your glossary as expected.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\author{foo}
\title{foo}
\date{}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a mark up language specially suited
    for scientific documents}
}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\maketitle
\printglossaries

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\label{cha:Introduction}

foo \gls{latex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Take a look at section 6 of the [`glossaries` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) for all available `\gls`-like commands.